# differential inequality on Arccos

Tags: inequality

I am a student of mathematics. I am struggling in proving an inequality which seems to very elementary. In fact, I would like to prove
$$
\pi x + 2 \arccos(x) \geq \pi
$$
for all $x \geq 0$. I checked the inequality by drawing the graph by my laptop. However, I don't have any idea to prove it. Maybe it is a really stupid question, but I am happy someone may help me. Thank you!

Comment: Note that $\arccos(x)$ is not defined for real $x > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
 \arccos(x) \ge \frac \pi 2 (1-x)
$$
holds for $0 \le x \le 1$ because $f(x) = \arccos(x)$ is concave on that interval: Its graph lies above the straight line which joints $(0, f(0))$ and $(1, f(1))$.

Or you substitute $u = \arccos(x)$, then the  inequality becomes
$$ 
\cos(u) \ge 1 - \frac 2 \pi u
$$
for $0 \le u \le \pi/2$, which is true because the cosine is concave on that interval.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your kind lecture!! I could understand the inequality!

Answer (score 0):

Just a more indepth explanation of concavity. It means that the slope of the line joining $(x,\cos^{-1}(x))$ and $(1,0)$ is *less than or equal* to the slope of the line joining $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(1,0)$. Thus: $-\dfrac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{1-x}=\dfrac{0 - \cos^{-1}(x)}{1-x} \le \dfrac{0-\frac{\pi}{2}}{1-0}= -\dfrac{\pi}{2}\implies \dfrac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{1-x} \ge \dfrac{\pi}{2}\implies \cos^{-1}(x) \ge \dfrac{\pi}{2}(1-x). $

Comment: Thank you for your kind additional remark! It was very helpful!!

Comment: Acutally that is not how I meant it. $f(x) = \arccos(x)$ is concave, and $L(x) = \frac \pi 2 (1-x)$ is the line joining $(0, f(0))$ and $(1, f(1))$. This immediately implies $f(x) \ge L(x)$ on the interval $[0, 1]$, directly from the definition of concavity.